# call program in interactive sql as400

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Is there a way to call a program from db2 interactive SQL in as400 (strsql)? this program receives an argument by reference and modify it's content. In CL, you simply call it like this:

```
call myprogram 12345
```

I need to be able to call it in interactive SQL, Is there any way or workaround to do this? like launching an OS command? for example in C you do system("your system command"). I couldn't find anything related to it.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=statements-call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STRSQL supports the SQL `CALL` statement.

The best option is to define the program as External SQL Stored procedure

```
--note 
----- numeric-->zoned decimal
----- decimal-->packed decimal
CREATE PROCEDURE MYLIB.MYPROGRAM_SP 
  (IN number numeric(5,0))  
LANGUAGE RPGLE
EXTERNAL NAME 'MYLIB/MYPROGRAM'
PARAMETER STYLE GENERAL;
```

Then you can
`CALL MYLIB.MYPROGRAM_SP(12345)`

Technically, every *PGM object on the IBM i is a stored procedure.  You can call it without explicitly defining it as shown above.  But assumptions are made about the parms in that case.  It's much better to provide the DB with the interface definition.

Note that STRSQL is a 20 year old tool, it has various limitations including not supporting OUT or INOUT parameters of stored procedures.

A much better choice is to use the Run SQL Scripts component of [IBM's Access Client Solutions (ACS)](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-client-solutions)

Comment: I was able to call it... An INOUT parameter, is similar to pass a parameter by reference? In other words, is impossible to send a variable from STRSQL so that the program modify its content?

Comment: you can send it, but STRSQL won't show you the changed value.  ACS can and will.

Comment: I began to use ACS and I created the SP. One argument is actually an array of chars.  If I declare it as IN, nothing throws error but it doesn't reflect the change. If I declare it as INOUT varchar(30), when I call it shows me an overflow error. The program I am calling only writes in the first 20 bytes. Do you maybe know what could be the cause of this? I call it like this:      CREATE VARIABLE MYVAR varchar(30) ; set MYVAR='1234567890123456789_';
call MYLIB.MYPROG_SP(MYVAR);

Comment: I replaced varchar with CHARACTER(30) and it worked. Your post was very helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: The Parma you define in the stored proc must match what the program is expecting.